# Can I customize how file information is displayed in Finder

Tags: finder, catalina

There are 3 things I need from Finder for my work: I need finder to be in "Columns" view, I need the window to be relatively small, and I need to be able to see the "date modified" and "file size" in the preview pane.

Since upgrading to Catalina, the icon image in the preview pane has gotten so big that I can't see any of the file information without scrolling - I've cropped the image but you can see how the file information isn't visible. I found out how to get rid of the "more" section underneath, but I still can't see the file information without scrolling.

[image]

I've tried going to View > Show View Options > Unclicking "Show Icon Previews", but that doesn't do anything. Basically I'd like for the preview image to be much smaller, or for the file information to show up on top.

Here's an example of how it used to look where all the preview info was compact - this is how I'd like it to look in Catalina:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get control of how things are shown in the Finder by clicking on the Finder icon in the dock. This should bring the Finder to the front. From there go to the View menu and click on it. Near the bottom of this menu is an option "Show View Options". Click on this and it opens a new panel where you can set things in the Finder View.  The image below shows the panel for setting the Finder view.

[image]

Comment: This does not actually answer the issue expressed in the OP.

Comment: his initial question was: Can I customize how file information is displayed in Finder. My answer addressed that.